# Label nodes created in SKS file manually are not loading

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

To make the how to play popup for my game I created a bunch of label nodes manually in the SKS file:

[image: SKSprite nodes]:
[image]

I had to make a lot of labels as they do not have a multi-line property. This is what it looks like when I actually run the code.

[image]

What can I do to fix this, is there an easy way out?

note: It is not the same labels that show up every time they are always different. Also, it is not only the labels as the sprite in the bottom right corner has the same problem.

Comment: The lack of multi-line label is annoying... You may try with some 3rd party : https://github.com/MKargin0/SKLabelNodePlus ... I suggested this one, because iirc, it makes a texture from a text, so it keeps draw calls on low (one label requires one draw pass). Still, whenever you want to update the text, you have to call its `drawLabel` method...

Comment: @Whirlwind luckily, I don't have to change the text but that solution is in objective C. is there a similar solution but in swift 3.

Comment: You can use bridging header @joshLor in order to use Obj-C classes in Swift and vice-versa.

Comment: @Whirlwind I added the class however I still have a few problem. The first minor problem is that the size feature of the class you linked to does not seem to work. The second problem is that that element as well as my title node and the back button sprite sometimes still don't show up

Comment: It is not me who wrote that class, so I can't really comment about issues you mentioned.

Comment: @Whirlwind What about the second question. Even after I have implemented the class some of the sprites still don't show up

Comment: Check the node count. If all nodes are there, then maybe it can be zPosition related issue. Still, I can't say much without a code/project that can reproduce an issue completely. Well, I could re-create the issue, but I leave that to you, while I am resting :)

Comment: @Whirlwind all of the nodes are there I can even use the back button when it doesn't appear. Which makes me think that the zposition is not the problem.

Comment: Check if label's position are correct and the alignment. I suspect that something is wrong with your code logic though...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this happens only when it's run in the simulator.  I don't believe it can handle the amount of draw calls it takes to draw that many labels at once. Run it on a device and all should be fine.

Comment: I am afraid that testing it on a phone does not seem to make a difference. More of  the labels usually show up but it still does not work.